# Documentum: Invalid property definition ID was supplied : cmis:path

Tags: cmis, documentum

I am sending this GET request to Documentum:

```
http://documentumserver/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/therepo/objects/  
9003bdd8053e179?filter=cmis:objectId,cmis:name,cmis:lastModificationDate,  
cmis:lastModifiedBy,cmis:path,cmis:changeToken,cmis:baseTypeId,cmis:objectTypeId  
&includeAllowableActions=true&includePolicyIds=false&includeRelationships=none  
&includeACL=false&renditionFilter=
```

To my surprise, Documentum replies with an error 40 Bad Request:

```
STATUS CODE:
400

EXCEPTION:
filterNotValid

ERROR:
Invalid property definition ID was supplied : cmis:path

STACK TRACE:
org.cmis.ws.CmisException: Invalid property definition ID was supplied : cmis:path
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.utils.CmisExceptionFactory.create(CmisExceptionFactory.java:24)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.utils.CmisExceptionBuilder.build(CmisExceptionBuilder.java:31)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.converter.object.DataObjectConverter.convertProperty(DataObjectConverter.java:241)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.converter.object.DataObjectConverter.convertProperties(DataObjectConverter.java:212)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.converter.object.DataObjectConverter.getCmisPropertiesByFilter(DataObjectConverter.java:202)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.converter.object.DataObjectConverter.toCmisObject(DataObjectConverter.java:124)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.action.GetObjectAction.execute(GetObjectAction.java:53)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.action.GetObjectAction.execute(GetObjectAction.java:34)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.filter.LinkedActionFilterChain.run(LinkedActionFilterChain.java:23)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.filter.RequestValidationFilter.doFilter(RequestValidationFilter.java:16)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.filter.LinkedActionFilterChain.run(LinkedActionFilterChain.java:21)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.rs.impl.resource.ObjectResource.getProperties(ObjectResource.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.rs.impl.web.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

What is bad in my request?

The error disappears if I remove `cmis:path,` from the request, is it forbidden by the CMIS protocol? The same request runs fine on most other CMIS servers.

Reproduced for both Documentum 7.1.0180.0293 and 7.3.0000.0176